# Package restore failed on .NET 7

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-7.0

I work on web project with ASP.NET Core 7 and Visual Studio 2022.

When I try to add a scaffolded item to my project, it throws an error:

> Package restore failed

I use Visual Studio 2022 and .NET 7.

Any idea what the problem could be? Is it related to Nuget packages?

I would be glad if someone help me with this.

Thank you.

Comment: could you pls let me know your ultimate goal? I met this issue when I tried to integrate EF core and adding asp.net core identity. But I didn't install `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design` package. I also met this issue when I just create a project via template but  I install another nuget package which version is the latest and it doesn't match the old packages from the default template. I can say your issue is related to the nuget packages but the solution is depending. You can search for "visual studio Package restore failed" in google to see others' issue and solutions.